# Pandas: do calculations in a subset of a dataset for each row index

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, dataset, dask

I have the following situation, which I solved but takes too long for the complexity of creating a subset of the dataframe for each index.

For each id and date in df, I have to create a subset of df_search which consists on the following

```
    lapse = 90
    period = df.loc[i, 'period']
    period_Nmonths_ago = (period - datetime.timedelta(lapse)).replace(day=1)
    
    #=== create the subset dataframe based on the id
    _id_df = df_search[df_search['id'] == _id].copy()
    
    #=== create another subset but just for the interval of N months ago.
    _id_df_interval = _id_df[(_id_df['period'] >= period_Nmonths_ago ) & (_id_df['period'] <= period)].copy()

    #=== do calculations on the time interval subset...
    cant_of_docs = len(list(_id_df_interval['document_id'].values))
```

And so on, I do calculations on **_id_df_interval**, but the most time consuming process is that of generating those subsets.

Is there a way to speed up computation of those steps? maybe a parallel approach?

Comment: Why do you create copies of the dataframe? (i.e. instead of having a single query that incorporates id and period)

Comment: I know, it's inconvenient, but I did it just for the sake of readability.

Comment: Would you be able to create a reproducible example, possibly using [`dask.dataframe.timeseries()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#dask.datasets.timeseries)?